# Eclipse(spring tool suite) Shuts Downs automatically on Server Startup (Eclipse Log File included)

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am using spring tool suite, i have successfully integrated jsf + primefaces + spring + hibernate(jpa)...however while running the project on server(tomcat) the IDE shuts down automatically..The COPY OF ECLIPSE LOG :

```
    #
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7816e542, pid=4068, tid=4072
    #
# JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [urlmon.dll+0x3e542]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00386400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4072, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000013
Registers:
EAX=0x6fcc5c3a, EBX=0x80004005, ECX=0x7816e57c, EDX=0x00000003
ESP=0x001297a8, EBP=0x001297b0, ESI=0x00000010, EDI=0x00000014
EIP=0x7816e542, EFLAGS=0x00010293

Top of Stack: (sp=0x001297a8)
0x001297a8:   00000001 6fcc5c38 001297c4 7816e50e
0x001297b8:   00000010 6fcc5c3a 6fcc5c20 001297d4
0x001297c8:   7816e4e2 00000010 6fcc5c38 00129a0c
0x001297d8:   7816b5e3 00000010 6fcc5c38 00000027
0x001297e8:   00129a28 6fcc5c20 781d748a 6fcc5c34
0x001297f8:   6fcc5c20 00000000 7c918681 00000000
0x00129808:   6d698998 00000033 6fd9c040 00750041
0x00129818:   006f0074 0061006d 00690074 004c0063 

Instructions: (pc=0x7816e542)
0x7816e522:   90 8b ff 55 8b ec 8b 45 0c 56 8b 75 08 57 6a 14
0x7816e532:   b9 7c e5 16 78 5f 8a 11 80 fa 2d 74 73 0f b6 d2
0x7816e542:   0f b6 14 32 c1 ea 04 66 8b 14 55 90 e5 16 78 66
0x7816e552:   89 10 0f b6 11 0f b6 14 32 40 40 83 e2 0f 66 8b 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x6fcc5c3a is an unknown value
EBX=0x80004005 is an unknown value
ECX=0x7816e57c is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000003 is an unknown value
ESP=0x001297a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00386400
EBP=0x001297b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00386400
ESI=0x00000010 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000014 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00030000,0x00130000],  sp=0x001297a8,  free space=997k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [urlmon.dll+0x3e542]  CreateAsyncBindCtx+0xcaa
C  [urlmon.dll+0x3e50e]  CreateAsyncBindCtx+0xc76
C  [urlmon.dll+0x3e4e2]  CreateAsyncBindCtx+0xc4a
C  [urlmon.dll+0x3b5e3]  Ordinal451+0x2b8
C  [urlmon.dll+0x351c9]  ObtainUserAgentString+0xb64
C  [urlmon.dll+0x3334f]  Ordinal335+0x48e
C  [mshtml.dll+0x33716b]  CreateHTMLPropertyPage+0x24ec1
C  [mshtml.dll+0x29d513]  Ordinal103+0x91477
C  [mshtml.dll+0xbbfc7]  DllGetClassObject+0x9ebd2
C  [mshtml.dll+0xceb96]  DllGetClassObject+0xb17a1
C  [mshtml.dll+0x29d2c0]  Ordinal103+0x91224
C  [mshtml.dll+0xa926d]  DllGetClassObject+0x8be78
C  [mshtml.dll+0xa9437]  DllGetClassObject+0x8c042
C  [mshtml.dll+0xa73c2]  DllGetClassObject+0x89fcd
C  [mshtml.dll+0xa7335]  DllGetClassObject+0x89f40
C  [mshtml.dll+0xb251a]  DllGetClassObject+0x95125
C  [mshtml.dll+0x8560a]  DllGetClassObject+0x68215
C  [mshtml.dll+0x2292a5]  Ordinal103+0x1d209
C  [mshtml.dll+0x2293b3]  Ordinal103+0x1d317
C  [mshtml.dll+0x1e2921]  Ordinal104+0x707c9
C  [mshtml.dll+0xeb213]  DllGetClassObject+0xcde1e
C  [mshtml.dll+0xf7341]  DllGetClassObject+0xd9f4c
C  [mshtml.dll+0x103108]  DllGetClassObject+0xe5d13
C  [mshtml.dll+0xeac11]  DllGetClassObject+0xcd81c
C  [jscript.dll+0x23a9a]  DllGetClassObject+0xc855
C  [jscript.dll+0x239e6]  DllGetClassObject+0xc7a1
C  [jscript.dll+0x24f26]  DllGetClassObject+0xdce1
C  [jscript.dll+0x24e80]  DllGetClassObject+0xdc3b
C  [jscript.dll+0x24b96]  DllGetClassObject+0xd951
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x243fc]  DllGetClassObject+0xd1b7
C  [jscript.dll+0x224c1]  DllGetClassObject+0xb27c
C  [jscript.dll+0x22d6d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbb28
C  [jscript.dll+0x24235]  DllGetClassObject+0xcff0
C  [jscript.dll+0x23114]  DllGetClassObject+0xbecf
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x243fc]  DllGetClassObject+0xd1b7
C  [jscript.dll+0x224c1]  DllGetClassObject+0xb27c
C  [jscript.dll+0x22d6d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbb28
C  [jscript.dll+0x24235]  DllGetClassObject+0xcff0
C  [jscript.dll+0x23114]  DllGetClassObject+0xbecf
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x23114]  DllGetClassObject+0xbecf
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x243fc]  DllGetClassObject+0xd1b7
C  [jscript.dll+0x224c1]  DllGetClassObject+0xb27c
C  [jscript.dll+0x22d6d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbb28
C  [jscript.dll+0x24235]  DllGetClassObject+0xcff0
C  [jscript.dll+0x23114]  DllGetClassObject+0xbecf
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x243fc]  DllGetClassObject+0xd1b7
C  [jscript.dll+0x224c1]  DllGetClassObject+0xb27c
C  [jscript.dll+0x22d6d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbb28
C  [jscript.dll+0x24235]  DllGetClassObject+0xcff0
C  [jscript.dll+0x23114]  DllGetClassObject+0xbecf
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x3595a]  DllCanUnloadNow+0x21da
C  [jscript.dll+0x24327]  DllGetClassObject+0xd0e2
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x243fc]  DllGetClassObject+0xd1b7
C  [jscript.dll+0x224c1]  DllGetClassObject+0xb27c
C  [jscript.dll+0x22d6d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbb28
C  [jscript.dll+0x24235]  DllGetClassObject+0xcff0
C  [jscript.dll+0x23114]  DllGetClassObject+0xbecf
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x3595a]  DllCanUnloadNow+0x21da
C  [jscript.dll+0x24327]  DllGetClassObject+0xd0e2
C  [jscript.dll+0x22a05]  DllGetClassObject+0xb7c0
C  [jscript.dll+0x228c5]  DllGetClassObject+0xb680
C  [jscript.dll+0x243fc]  DllGetClassObject+0xd1b7
C  [jscript.dll+0x224c1]  DllGetClassObject+0xb27c
C  [jscript.dll+0x22d6d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbb28
C  [jscript.dll+0x24235]  DllGetClassObject+0xcff0
C  [jscript.dll+0x24f93]  DllGetClassObject+0xdd4e
C  [jscript.dll+0x213ab]  DllGetClassObject+0xa166
C  [jscript.dll+0x212e5]  DllGetClassObject+0xa0a0
C  [jscript.dll+0xb551]
C  [jscript.dll+0x2317d]  DllGetClassObject+0xbf38
    ...<more frames>...

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/MSG;)I
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+578
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x65df1400 JavaThread "Thread-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=448, stack(0x6f030000,0x6f130000)]
  0x65f99400 JavaThread "Process monitor" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3308, stack(0x6c1c0000,0x6c2c0000)]
  0x6627d400 JavaThread "Input Stream Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1940, stack(0x6c0c0000,0x6c1c0000)]
  0x65d36800 JavaThread "Output Stream Monitor" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3304, stack(0x6bfc0000,0x6c0c0000)]
  0x65d36400 JavaThread "Output Stream Monitor" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=276, stack(0x6bec0000,0x6bfc0000)]
  0x65dc9400 JavaThread "Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=492, stack(0x6bdc0000,0x6bec0000)]
  0x661a0400 JavaThread "org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3260, stack(0x6b0e0000,0x6b1e0000)]
  0x6664e400 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3184, stack(0x6aee0000,0x6afe0000)]
  0x66359400 JavaThread "Reporting Thread-1 (Spring UAA/1.0.2)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1524, stack(0x682c0000,0x683c0000)]
  0x667a9800 JavaThread "Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=552, stack(0x6ad20000,0x6ae20000)]
 0x6657d400 JavaThread "Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=4044, stack(0x699a0000,0x69aa0000)]
 0x662bc000 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=2444, stack(0x698a0000,0x699a0000)]
  0x66733c00 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=648, stack(0x69710000,0x69810000)]
  0x66331c00 JavaThread "Event Batch Processing (Spring UAA/1.0.2)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2820, stack(0x69610000,0x69710000)]
 0x6630e400 JavaThread "Synchronizer (Spring UAA/1.0.2)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3504, stack(0x69510000,0x69610000)]
 0x65d91400 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=2860, stack(0x69400000,0x69500000)]
0x661e5000 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3388, stack(0x69300000,0x69400000)]
 0x65892c00 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3980, stack(0x69180000,0x69280000)]
  0x64e72800 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3676, stack(0x68b90000,0x68c90000)]
  0x65f9d400 JavaThread "Provisioning Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3904, stack(0x68a10000,0x68b10000)]
  0x66366c00 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3884, stack(0x68630000,0x68730000)]
0x65ff9400 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3840, stack(0x68140000,0x68240000)]
0x6626d400 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x68040000,0x68140000)]
0x65f34c00 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1620, stack(0x67dc0000,0x67ec0000)]
0x65cae800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=536, stack(0x67bc0000,0x67cc0000)]
 0x65e47800 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2608, stack(0x66e30000,0x66f30000)]
 0x65d31400 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=2480, stack(0x66ba0000,0x66ca0000)]
  0x65d42400 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1160, stack(0x66ca0000,0x66da0000)]
0x65ef9400 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2172, stack(0x66aa0000,0x66ba0000)]
 0x64e64400 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3828, stack(0x66990000,0x66a90000)]
  0x65fe8800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1660, stack(0x66080000,0x66180000)]
  0x657b7400 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1708, stack(0x65b80000,0x65c80000)]
  0x656ed800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=572, stack(0x65a80000,0x65b80000)]
  0x64e3f400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2032, stack(0x654b0000,0x655b0000)]
  0x64e39000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2036, stack(0x653b0000,0x654b0000)]
  0x64e37800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1964, stack(0x652b0000,0x653b0000)]
0x64e36400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4092, stack(0x651b0000,0x652b0000)]
 0x64e29800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4088, stack(0x650b0000,0x651b0000)]
0x64e24c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4084, stack(0x64fb0000,0x650b0000)]
=>0x00386400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4072, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

Other Threads:
 0x64e21000 VMThread [stack: 0x64eb0000,0x64fb0000] [id=4080]
0x64e4a000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x655b0000,0x656b0000] [id=1408]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 84992K, used 58569K [0x02a30000, 0x08660000, 0x17f80000)
  eden space 75584K,  77% used [0x02a30000, 0x06362668, 0x07400000)
  from space 9408K,   0% used [0x07400000, 0x07400000, 0x07d30000)
  to   space 9408K,   0% used [0x07d30000, 0x07d30000, 0x08660000)
tenured generation   total 188608K, used 113163K [0x17f80000, 0x237b0000, 0x42a30000)
 the space 188608K,  59% used [0x17f80000, 0x1ee02c78, 0x1ee02e00, 0x237b0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 115712K, used 115520K [0x42a30000, 0x49b30000, 0x62a30000)
   the space 115712K,  99% used [0x42a30000, 0x49b003f8, 0x49b00400, 0x49b30000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x009b0000, 0x013e8000, 0x029b0000)
 total_blobs=4922 nmethods=4688 adapters=164 free_code_cache=22866688 largest_free_block=256

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0044e000     D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\STS.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x658b0000 - 0x65905000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x65990000 - 0x659c8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x774e0000 - 0x7761e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x67030000 - 0x670a0000     D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\699\2\.cp\swt-win32-4233.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x763b0000 - 0x763f9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x74d90000 - 0x74dfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USP10.dll
0x670a0000 - 0x67186000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WININET.dll
0x67190000 - 0x67199000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x78130000 - 0x78263000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll
0x671a0000 - 0x6738b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll
0x77a80000 - 0x77b15000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77b20000 - 0x77b32000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x675f0000 - 0x6760d000     D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\699\2\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-4233.dll
0x67610000 - 0x677bb000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.22791_x-ww_c8dff154\gdiplus.dll
0x678f0000 - 0x678fe000     D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\117\2\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x66fb0000 - 0x66fbf000     D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\120\2\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x66fd0000 - 0x67029000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f1c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RASAPI32.DLL
0x76e90000 - 0x76ea2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasman.dll
0x76eb0000 - 0x76edf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\TAPI32.dll
0x76e80000 - 0x76e8e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
0x77c70000 - 0x77c95000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msv1_0.dll
0x76790000 - 0x7679c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\cryptdll.dll
0x67ec0000 - 0x67efa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\oleacc.dll
0x76fd0000 - 0x7704f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77050000 - 0x77115000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
0x75cf0000 - 0x75d81000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mlang.dll
0x68730000 - 0x68788000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x68cb0000 - 0x68f75000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x6d780000 - 0x6d788000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77b62000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Apphelp.dll
0x76380000 - 0x76385000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msimg32.dll
0x73bc0000 - 0x73bc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dciman32.dll
0x6c470000 - 0x6cf0c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ieframe.dll
0x7e720000 - 0x7e7d0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SXS.DLL
0x6dea0000 - 0x6e45e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtml.dll
0x6d220000 - 0x6d249000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msls31.dll
0x746f0000 - 0x7471a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msimtf.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76c5e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x76c90000 - 0x76cb8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
0x72d20000 - 0x72d29000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wdmaud.drv
0x72d10000 - 0x72d18000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msacm32.drv
0x77be0000 - 0x77bf5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSACM32.dll
0x77bd0000 - 0x77bd7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\midimap.dll
0x722b0000 - 0x722b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\sensapi.dll
0x6f1e0000 - 0x6f294000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\jscript.dll
0x6d730000 - 0x6d769000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dxtrans.dll
0x76b20000 - 0x76b31000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ATL.DLL
0x6d5d0000 - 0x6d5dc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ImgUtil.dll
0x6d5e0000 - 0x6d5ea000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ddrawex.dll
0x73760000 - 0x737ab000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x6d5f0000 - 0x6d5fe000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\pngfilt.dll
0x6f130000 - 0x6f187000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dxtmsft.dll
0x77920000 - 0x77a13000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;D:\springsource\sts-3.0.0.RELEASE;
USERNAME=Aeshyu
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 2085996k(763556k free), swap 4024484k(2285216k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_25-b06), built on Apr 14 2011 01:04:32 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Wed Nov 28 18:45:55 2012
elapsed time: 267 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar thing happen to me. In my case there was a bad jar file (invalid ZIP format) polluting one of my projects and what I did in the end was wipe the workspace and start again (delete the .metadata directory and start the IDE fresh), omitting that project by a process of elimination and re-creating it from scratch.

You could try starting STS with -refresh (in a command line).  It helps sometimes with Eclipse issues, but this one looks more serious.

You could also try upgrading your JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...however i tried but still facing the same issue...i have also tried to increase the buffer size in web.xml and the heap size of the tomcat..but still facing the same issue.